# Как создать пустое приложение в yii2 basic

Tags: framework, php, yii

Есть шаблон, хочу разрабатывать под него всё свое, но так как в папках Views,Models и Controllers уже есть демо-элементы, а они мне не нужны. Если их удалить, то появляетсья куча ошибок. Выходит для создания сайта их обязательно оставлять даже не используя? 
Ошибки после удаления

> Controllers/SiteController.php 
> Views/layout/main.php  
> Models/User.php

Comment: Прежде чем удалять что-то, нужно выяснить зачем оно там. При большом желании можно архитектуру приложения изменить (написать с нуля). Изучайте, постепенно.

Comment: Никак. У разработчиков Yii своя атмосфера, в ней это не предусмотрено. Но, строго говоря, если оставить голый Yii, то он и отдавать-то вам не должен вообще ничего (это фреймворк, не приложение), так что не очень понятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.